# Move DocumentFile

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

I'm trying to move all files from `source` to `destination` folder.

Getting `destinate` URI picked by user using SAF:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == INTENT_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            destinationUri = resultData.getData();
            destinationDocumentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, destinationUri);
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(destinationUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
```

Creating `source` `DocumentFile` instance (`source` folder placed on internal storage, `destination` folder placed on movable sdcard):

```
sourceFile =new File("sdcard/somewhere/music");
sourceDocumentFile =DocumentFile.fromFile(sourceFile);
```

And moving files from `source` to `destinate`:

```
DocumentFile documentFiles[]= sourceDocumentFile.listFiles();
    for (DocumentFile doc:documentFiles) {
        DocumentsContract.moveDocument(getContentResolver(),
                doc.getUri(),
                doc.getParentFile().getUri(),
                destinationUri);
    }
```

But I got that exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.ContentProviderClient.call(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)' on a null object reference
                                                               at android.provider.DocumentsContract.moveDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1237)
                                                               at android.provider.DocumentsContract.moveDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1219)
                                                               at mo.drud.lmcc.MainActivity.move(MainActivity.java:96)
```

Android 7.1.1 if it matters

Comment: `sourceFile =new File("sdcard/somewhere/music");`. Dont use hard coded paths. And if you do it would be `sourceFile =new File("/sdcard/somewhere/music");`. And if the source is a directory then why not name it as such to keep ykur code readable `sourceDir =new File("/sdcard/somewhere/music");`.

Comment: `doc.getParentFile().getUri(),`. Think that  `doc.getParentFile()`returns `null`. Check before use. Maybe you better use `sourceDocumentFile.getUri()`.

Comment: Problem is null `ContentProvider`, but anyway your suggestion doesn't work

Comment: Unclear what you mean with null ContentProvider. If you want help you should explain bettdr.

Comment: Actually none of `DocumentsContract`'s methods (move, rename, copy, delete) doesn't work with the same `NullPointer` error

Comment: These file:// uris are a problem ii think. You could try to select twice a directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TRUE. A source dir and a destination. Then get it running with content:// sheme first.

Comment: I do not get the exception here. But DocumentsContract.moveDocument() returns null instead of a valid uri.

Comment: any solutions? Also experiencing the same issues